# What are the data structures used to implement the Process Control Block in Unix?

Tags: operating-system

I am taking an operating systems course and we have talked about what a process control block is,    what is stored in it, what purpose it servers, and I understand all of that, but we didn't really touch on what data structure is actually used to make it. After googling it, I've come across two structures: either a linked list or an array is used. I realize that the structure could possible differ based on the operating system, but I was wondering exactly what data structures are used to create one, specifically in the Unix operating system (since I am using a Unix machine)?

Comment: Well, you could look at the source code.  I'm sure that will help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `doubly-linked list` data-structure is used 'generally' to implement Process Control Block! In UNIX also, the PCB is implemented as a doubly-linked list.

But,in case if your OS (talking about custom OS) is lightweight,then you can get off by using simpler data-structure like arrays! But,in general,PCB's are a very large data-structure and hence, advised to store in doubly-linked list which can be accommodated for any process to any level(storing all possible sort of info about process).

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452484/pc-and-cpu-registers-when-context-switching-happens/24459050#24459050) of mine,here also I have mentioned in the last line the same answer...

Comment: Thank you so much! I would up vote you, but I don't have enough reputation.